# Var List for function suggestion

Tags: java, reverse

I made  a simple program to reverse lists. Now I was trying to reverse a string so I converted it into a character array and assigned it to a variable charz.But my function only accepts a List of strings.

Now in python I could have a list of multiple variable types like a = [1,"hello",1.3] and it wouldn't be a problem is there a same way to make a list as such so I can use it in my function? How do I make it accept this variable charz without making a new function just for this particular data type.

```
package test_proj1;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class TestClass1
{
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        List<String> sent = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Jake","you","are"));
        System.out.println("Without reversal the inuilt list is "+sent);
        sent = lisrev(sent);
        System.out.println("After reversal the list is "+ sent);
        System.out.println("\nNow then enter a word for me: ");
        String word = reader.nextLine();
        char[] charz = word.toCharArray();
        // List<String> revword = lisrev(charz);  
        // I want the above line to work but it won't because my function
        // lisrev will only accept  a list of type String




    }
    public static List<String> lisrev (List<String> lis)
    {
        int lastindex = lis.size() - 1;
        List<String> newlis = new ArrayList<String>();


        while (lastindex != -1)
        {
            String elem = lis.get(lastindex);
            newlis.add(elem);
            lastindex -= 1;
        }


        return newlis;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can write a function that works on a generic list. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char[] charz = word.toCharArray();
String wordReversed = "";
for (int i=charz.length-1; i>=0; i--){
      wordReversed+= charz[i];
}
System.out.println(wordReversed);
```

The result will be for example:

```
Without reversal the inuilt list is [Jake, you, are]
After reversal the list is [are, you, Jake]

Now then enter a word for me: 
Hello My name is Sam, How are you today?
?yadot uoy era woH ,maS si eman yM olleH
```

furthermore, if you wanna reverse a sentence from the user you can do something like this:

```
List<String> theWord = new ArrayList<String>();
String eachWord="";
for(int i=0; i<charz.length; i++){
    eachWord+=charz[i]; // append the char to the String
    if(charz[i]==' ' || i==charz.length-1){
       if(!eachWord.replace(" ", "").equals("")){ // for the followed spaces
          theWord.add(eachWord.replace(" ", "")); // add the word 
       }
       eachWord = ""; // start new string
    }
}
System.out.println(lisrev(theWord));
```

the result will be for example (notice the spaces)

```
Without reversal the inuilt list is [Jake, you, are]
After reversal the list is [are, you, Jake]
Now then enter a word for me: 
Hello My name is Sam,   How are   you today 
[?, today, you, are, How, Sam,, is, name, My, Hello]
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot :)  Makes sense now thanks for detailed explanation with an example, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your list to contain several different data types then declare your list as **Object**, for example:

```
List<Object> sent = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList("Jake","you","are", 20, "years", "old", "and", 70.3, "inches", "high"));
for (int i = 0; i < sent.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(sent.get(i).toString());
}
```

If however you want to break the elements of the list into specific data type variables like String, int, double, etc then you will need to cast to it, for example:

```
String name = (String) sent.get(0); //or use: sent.get(0).toString();
int age = (int) sent.get(3);
double height = (double) sent.get(7);
```

If you want a double or integer type within the list to be String then you can do either:

For integers, double, float, etc:

```
String age = sent.get(3).toString();
```

OR

```
String age = String.valueOf(sent.get(3));
```

Comment: Ah this is what I was looking for <Object> makes a lot of sense thanks :)